# How to hide scrollbar in QScrollArea?

Tags: qt, qscrollarea

How can one hide the scrollbars in a `QScrollArea`? Currently I use the `hide()` method on the scrollbars returned by `QScrollArea::horizontalScrollBar()` and `QScrollArea::verticalScrollBar()` but the space reserved for scrollbars still remains. Obviously this looks very ugly and is not space efficient. If I remove the scrollbars altogether I can no longer easily scroll to a specific point using `QScrollBar::setValue()`.

Answer (score 22):

You can hide it using a style sheet.
Use `height:0px;` to hide the horizontal scroll bar and `width=0px;` to hide the vertical scroll bar.
Like that:

```
horizontalScrollBar()->setStyleSheet("QScrollBar {height:0px;}");
verticalScrollBar()->setStyleSheet("QScrollBar {width:0px;}");
```

And voila!.No scroll bars, and you can still manipulate them using `setValue()`.

Answer (score 20):

Use this code:

```
QAbstractScrollArea::setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy( Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff )
QAbstractScrollArea::setVerticalScrollBarPolicy( Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff )
```

Comment: If I do it that way I can no longer scroll to a specific point using QScrollBar::setValue() (because the scrollbars do not exist)

Comment: If you need a scroll bar when needed, use the policy: Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded.
If you want to scroll content programmatic, use QAbstractScrollArea::scrollContentsBy ( int dx, int dy )

Comment: [Apparenly](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#scrollContentsBy) you should call scrollbar's `setValue()` instead of `scrollContentsBy()`.

Answer (score 4):

This piece of code can do the job:

```
 setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
 verticalScrollBar()->hide();
 verticalScrollBar()->resize(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Qt documents](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractscrollarea.html) for `scrollContentsBy()`:

> Calling this function in order to scroll programmatically is an error, use the scroll bars instead (e.g. by calling QScrollBar::setValue() directly).